# CodeIgniter form validation 'matches' for multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to validate a form in CodeIgniter but the data that I get is in a multidimensional array. I want to do a simple `matches` validation for a password field but it always says that the passwords do not match no matter what I type in the corresponding form. The input I get looks like this:

```
data[name]:dsafsadfasdf
data[password]:123456
data[password_confirm]:123456
```

And I have the following set for validation:

```
$registrationValidation = array(
                        array(
                            'field' => 'data[password]',
                            'label' => 'Password',
                            'rules' => 'required|matches[data[password_confirm]]',
                            'errors' => array(
                                'required' => 'Some message',
                                'matches' => 'Another message',
                            ),
                        ),
                    );
```

The `required` part and any other validation that I have (`min_length` for example) works just fine, however it looks like the `matches` part does not like the multidimensional array. Any ideas how to trick it elegantly without making a callback function?

Comment: Is `data` actually a variable, i.e. `$data`?

Comment: No, not really. It's how it's passed in the header sent to the server.